# Add header to correlation matrix in Spark

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am applying correlation on a csv file using apache spark, when loading data I am obliged to skip the first row as a header which are columns in the dataset otherwise I can't load the data.

I get the correlation computed but when I got the correlation matrix, I can't add the columns name as a header in the new matrix. How to get the matrix with its header? This what I have tried:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{ Vector, Vectors }
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.Statistics
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val data = sc.textFile(strfilePath).mapPartitionsWithIndex {
  case (index, iterator) => if (index == 0) iterator.drop(1) else iterator
}

val inputMatrix = data.map { line =>
  val values = line.split(",").map(_.toDouble)
  Vectors.dense(values)
}

val correlationMatrix = Statistics.corr(inputMatrix, "pearson")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spark 2.0+ you can load a csv file into a dataframe using the command:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("filePath")
```

The correlations between different columns can then be computed with

```
df.stat.corr("col1", "col2", "pearson")
```

Comment: you mean , that i need to load data as dataframe if i want to manipulate columns ?

Comment: @MaherHTB You don't need to but it's easier as all columns are given names according to your header. However, an alternative would be to use the current approach and simply read the header from the file separately using `Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.head`.

Comment: I asked you because , the fact of saving Dataframe into a csv file took too much time than saving an RDD[Vector] or a matrix in a csv file.Would you please tell me how whould be my code updated to get correlation matrix with header  if i use the second approach ,many thanks

Comment: Not sure why that should be. Maybe you can try saving as a .parquet file? In any case, when the file is saved it should be possible to read it as either an RDD or a dataframe. It doesn't matter how the csv file was created in the beginning.